# Splitting the dates in Sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

```
ID  No     FromDate        Todate
1   111    2017-03-01      2017-03-15
2   111    2017-03-01      2017-03-08
3   111    2017-03-08      2017-03-15
```

Have Couple of Questions:

1. How to Identify the dates and Corss Dateband
2. Split First Id Into Two Dates
   like  `2017-03-01 to 2017-03-08` And `2017-03-08 to 2017-03-15`

Comment: 1) what is a Corss Dateband ?. 2) how are those two dates split ?.

Comment: you're going to have to explain the business logic a lot better. Maybe give 2 or 3 examples so a pattern can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate) function that SQL Server provided:

`SELECT ID, NO, FromDate, FromDate + ROUND( DATEDIFF( DAY, FromDate, Todate) / 2, 0),  Todate FROM YOUR_TABLE`

Hopefully, it helps you.